# Visual Studio 2015 Web Test Redirect/Dynamic Parameter issues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing, web-testing

I'm new to the load testing game and have been going crazy with this issue of redirecting and storing dynamic parameters.

I have a web test that would do the following:

1. Navigate to a candidate facing URL (e.g.: https://testsite.com/page/recruit.aspx)

   - When this happens, a redirect occurs in order to check what device the candidate is using.  (https://testsite.com/other/DetectDevice.aspx) and then back to recruit.aspx
2. I should be able to then click a continue button and proceed to other pages where the same scenario occurs.

On each page there's hidden fields (__VIEWSTATE, __EVENTTARGET, etc.) All of which are dynamic and unique to their respective page (they are regenerated for the next page).

I generated the code manually and tried to hardcode some things just to get the test to pass, but even once I got to a passing state I realized it wasn't actually doing anything.

The errors I get are: **"No hidden fields were found in the response: Request failed: Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.__VIEWSTATE' not found in test context"** and **"302 object moved to HERE"** where "here" reads "This page can't be displayed"

Images to the start up of my test:
[image]
[image]

I'm not really sure where to go from here so any advice would be helpful.  If you need any further information please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: See this answer and read the linked pages: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36567215/546871

Comment: I've read through those documents a handful of times now and i'm still quite lost.  I'll have a little more time tomorrow to go through them once more, but so far they haven't helped a great deal unless i'm just entirely misunderstanding my issue.  Oh and thank you for the response :) They're greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are asking a general "how do I debug a webtest?" question. The errors such as "No hidden fields found" and "hidden.xxx not found in context" are symptoms that the request or the preceding one are not correct. Typically some item of dynamic data has not been found and included in a request. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16944240/546871